# Where to put config blocks according to Ruby convention?

Tags: ruby, coding-style, config

Which is more correct? 
I know that both of them "work" but what is the agreed upon convention for where to place configuration blocks?

This:

```
class Something
  Library1.config do |config|
    #call configuration methods
  end

  Library2.config do |config|
    #call configuration methods
  end

  def initialize
    #build the object
  end
end
```

or this?

```
class Something
  def initialize
    Library1.config do |config|
      #call configuration methods
    end

    Library2.config do |config|
      #call configuration methods
    end

    #build the object
  end
end
```

Comment: Probably the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no one right answer. You just have to know what you want in each case, because they do different things.

- The former configures the libraries when the class is first loaded
- The latter configures the library every time an instance is created.

Both are things you could potentially want, but *I would probably do **neither***.

Why? Because you are modifying the global state of a module that many classes might rely on, so you *probably only want to configure it once*. Instead, I would put the configuration into a dedicated config file that gets loaded upon initialization. This is commonly done in e.g. rails (see: Everything in the `config/` directory of a rails project).

#### Example

I've constructed an example illustrating the different behaviors, and how a rouge class (`Spoiler`) can confuse everyone when changing the global configuration of a module. In this example, the `Spoiler` changes the configuration twice, clearly affecting `NaiveUser`.

```
module Configurable
  def self.configuration
    @configuration ||= { number: 1 }
  end

  def self.config
    yield(configuration)
  end
end

class NaiveUser
  def configurable_number
    Configurable.configuration[:number]
  end
end

puts NaiveUser.new.configurable_number

class Spoiler
  Configurable.config do |c|
    c[:number] = "first spoil"
  end

  def initialize
    Configurable.config do |c|
      c[:number] = "spoiled again"
    end
  end
end

puts NaiveUser.new.configurable_number

Spoiler.new

puts NaiveUser.new.configurable_number
```

The output of this program is

```
1
first spoil
spoiled again
```

This example could e.g. be extended to an example where a stateful `NaiveUser` erroneously blends results from two different configurations under the (faulty) assumption that the configuration would remain constant.

Comment: This is exactly the type of answer I was looking for. Thank you!